# How to add '-' after each character in string using regex in python3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to add '-' after every char in string except at start and end.

Example-
Input - 'abcd'
Expected Output - 'a-b-c-d'
 I tried -

```
Str1 = re.sub(r'([a-z])([a-z])',r'\1-\2',Str1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
s = 'abcd'
print("-".join(s))
# --> a-b-c-d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string `join` is probably the best option here, but if you wanted to stick with your regex approach, here is one way to do it:

```
inp = "abcd"
output = re.sub(r'([a-z])(?!$)', '\\1-', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
a-b-c-d
```

The idea here is to capture each letter and replace with that letter, followed by a dash, if the letter be *not* the final letter in the string.